# stack for loading log files into cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I would like to periodically (hourly) load my application logs into Cassandra for analysis using pig.

How is this typically done?  Are there project(s) that focus on this?

I see [mumakil](https://github.com/Ganglion/mumakil) is commonly used to bulk-load data.  I could write a cron job built around that, but was hoping for something more robust than the job I would whip-up.

I'm also willing to modify the applications to store the data in another format (like syslog or directly to Cassandra) if that is preferable.  Though in that case I would be worried about data-loss should Cassandra be unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider loading them into HDFS using [Flume](https://cwiki.apache.org/FLUME/), since these projects were designed for this purpose.  You can then use Pig directly against your unstructured/semi-structured log data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using Flume, you'll need to write a custom Flume sink (not hard). You can model it on https://github.com/geminitech/logprocessing.

If you are wanting to use Pig, I agree with the other poster that you should use HDFS (or S3). Hadoop is designed to work very well with block storage where the blocks are huge. This prevents the terrible IO performance you get from doing lots of disk seeks and network IO. While you CAN use Pig with Cassandra, you're going to have trouble with the Cassandra data model and you're going to have much worse performance.

However, if you really want to use Cassandra and you aren't dead set on Flume, I would recommend using Kafka and Storm.

My workflow for loading log files into Cassandra with Storm is:

1. Kafka collects the logs (e.g. with the log4j appender)
2. Logs enter the storm cluster using storm-kafka
3. Log line is parsed and inserted into Cassandra using custom Storm bolts (It's extremely easy to write Storm bolts). There is also a storm-cassandra bolt already available.